# Disambiguating tag CSP

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

We have in stackoverflow both [csp](/questions/tagged/csp) and [content-security-policy](/questions/tagged/content-security-policy) that seem to refer to the same [topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy), at least in tag description. This tags might eventually be made synonyms and merged.

However, there is actually a [conflicting acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) for csp, and the csp tag appears to be used in many question with this meaning. I noticed that while reviewing edit suggestions that attempted to remove csp tag from communicating sequential processes questions (that may already be finished if people approved the edit requests).

I tried to create and set back on the questions a [communicating-sequential-processes](/questions/tagged/communicating-sequential-processes) tag, but it does not fit the 25 chars limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and manually retagged the 16 leftover [csp](/questions/tagged/csp) questions.  If it reappears maybe it'll be worth making it a synonym, but given the apparently low usage I'd vote to just let it be culled for now and only keep the more specific tags.

I didn't see any about communicating sequential processes.

I do see that you've been adding a [comm-sequential-processes](/questions/tagged/comm-sequential-processes) tag to some questions which doesn't seem like a bad solution.

Comment: ok for csp; actually I dont like the new tag, is csp (concept) small enough to be under the hat of concurrent-programming in your opinion?

Comment: @guido I don't think that we should remove informative tags just because they're awkwardly named.  Better would be increasing the tag length limit (which seems arbitrary).

Comment: sure that's why I posted this message, having some more characters for tags would be nice as well